# Narrator reading empty document for text-only informative modal popup

Tags: html, modal-dialog, accessibility, microsoft-edge, narrator

I am developing a webpage which shows a text-only modal popup upon clicking a button on the webpage. The issue is:
Narrator is saying aria-label for the popup followed by "empty document", but the popup contains a paragraph of information and an image. Why is this happening or  is it expected ?

NB: This issue is experienced only in Narrator, where as Jaws and NVD A are working perfect.
Using : Narrator(Latest Update) and Edge(44.17763.1.0)

The problem seems to be solved by inserting an empty span element, but then narrator reads aria-label twice

```
<div aria-label ="Popup has been opened" aria-hidden="false">
<button aria-label="Close Button" aria-hidden="false"> X </button>
<div>
    <img src=".."/>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Some text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Narrator is saying aria-label for the popup followed by "empty document"  but actually it should be reading only the aria-label, then user can use arrow keys to read through the contents

Comment: how does it sound with other screen readers (jaws and nvda) on other browsers (firefox and internet explorer)?  where do you put your focus when the dialog displays?  note that you shouldn't say "button" in your `aria-label` because you're already using a <button> element so the screen reader will tell you it's a button.  your label can just be "close"

Comment: Jaws + IE is working perfect as expected. The issue is faced only during Narrator. The focus is on close button while modal popup is opened. Yeah , thanks for the correction on aria-label

Comment: so it could be a narrator or edge problem.  i don't have w10 so can't try edge, but does edge have an accessibility tree viewer from the code inspector (f12)?  firefox and chrome both do.  if you can verify that edge is correctly surfacing the accessibility properties of the element, then it's a narrator problem.  however, i would not necessarily try to code around it if your sample code is semantically correct.  you should always lean towards writing the proper html and not try to hack around a bug in the browser or screen reader.

Comment: I too agree. Since this is a narrator-only issue, I'm trying to make it as an open issue during deployment @slugolicious

Comment: jaws and nvda ok with edge?  that would also indicate that edge is surfacing the info correctly and make it a narrator bug